# Find and/or Edit file names in a directory hierarchy

Tags: python-3.8

I created a python program and I used import.os... so I want to convert it but not with import.os
can someone help me?
So the main goal is the user to be able to search a path and also to change the file name but i only know the import.os method.

```
 tree.py
import os
import sys
import time
#logo
print("_______ _______________ ______  ___")
print("___    |___  __/__  __ \___   |/  /")
print("__  /| |__  /   _  / / /__  /|_/ /")
print("_  ___ |_  /    / /_/ / _  /  / /")
print("/_/  |_|/_/     \____/  /_/  /_/")
#os.getcwd() Cwd is for current working directory in python. This returns the path of the current python directory as a string in Python.
path = os.chdir('/root')
bl = os.getcwd()
#To change our current working directories in python, we use the chdir() method.
print(os.listdir())
os.chdir(bl)
print("your current location is: ", path)
change = input("Do you want to change your directory (yes/no): ")
if change == "yes":
        dir = input("Add new Location: ")
        if dir == bl and dir == path:
                print("cant go to the same directory")
        else:
                print("please wait")
                time.sleep(2)
                os.chdir(dir)
                print(os.path.exists(dir))
                print(os.getcwd())
prDIR = input("Do you want to print the files (yes/no) : ")
if prDIR == "yes":
        for f in os.listdir():
                file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
                print(file_name.split('-'))
change2 = input("Do you want to change again your DIR: ")
if change2 == "yes":
        dir = input("Add a new location: ")
        if dir == bl:
                print("cant go to the same place")
        else:
                print("please wait")
                time.sleep(1)
                os.chdir(dir)
                print(os.path.exists(dir))
                print(os.getcwd())
print("your current location is: ", path, dir)
pat = input("Do you want to rename this Dir (yes/no) : ")
if pat == "yes":
        ch = input("Enter the path but renamed: ")
        time.sleep(2)
        os.rename(dir, ch)
        print(ch)
```

Comment: what a strange desire

Comment: damn can you help me with this?